# Pass list of view to another fragment using intent

Tags: java, android

Just started making applications. Came through a problem though that how pass list of views into another fragment in a activity?

Comment: Passing views between fragments in an activity is a very strange approach. Most likely there is a better way of implementing whatever it is that you are trying to do.

Comment: you can use the newInstance() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the same views in different fragments, right? There are two ways:
1. using static variables, so you can access the those views anywhere
2. pass the values of these views to other fragments and then create the same list of views and set the value.

Answer (score 0):

You should not communicate between Fragment directly. Instead, you should communicate via the Activity which hosting the fragments. It's usually using Interface. You can check https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html